# How to know if execution program is ok at windows?

Tags: windows, scripting

How to know if execution program is ok at windows?

I prepare a bat file that runs several programs and I handle exceptions in case of errors .

On linux a program return a code after execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends if the windows executable you run returns a return code.  The return code is stored in the %ERRORLEVEL% variable.